# Extracting data from an API response to put into table in Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I have an API call which results several hundred records. I start by converting the URL to a string (there are varying parameters)

```
$res = Http::get($str);
$result = $res->json();
```

This works fine and when I dd the result I can see the response is fine

[image]

I want to record this in a table by using a `foreach` loop but if I try, for example, to assign the period I just get a key not known error.

I tried to find the period and do a dd with:

```
foreach ($result as $im)
    {
        $period = $im['period'];
        dd($period);
    }
```

but I get:

> Undefined array key "period"

Comment: Please do not display screenshots of `dd()` output on Stack Overflow.  Always present your array/object payloads as copy-pasted `var_export()` text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your accessing that property too early in the array, you need to access via `response` and `data` keys first.

```php
foreach ($result['response']['data'] as $im)
{
    $period = $im['period'];
    dd($period);
}
```

Comment: Please vote to close basic duplicate questions which are asked in 2023 instead of answering them.  (Virtually all basic programming task are duplicates on Stack Overflow because there are millions of pages banked up over 15 years of feverish Q&A.)